# Passing a string "dynamically" as a class name in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent

Let's say you have a string:

```
String string_name; //assign whatever value
```

And you have an intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), string_name.class);
```

This obviously doesn't work. AS doesn't recognise **string_name** as a class (although IT EXISTS as an activity in the main folder). The forname method didn't work for me either (unless I did it wrong).

I have 10 activities/classes listed name1, name2, name3, etc... And after I'm done with each activity, the program goes to a "Transition" activity page, which then redirects to the next activity at run time. So after the user is done with name1 activity, the program redirects him to the "Transition" page. And after that I'm trying to send them to name2 activity. And so on.

What I'm trying to do is assign the name of name1, name2, activities to a string (**string_name** in this case) in the "Transition" activity/class. After a couple of lines of code, I managed to retrieve the name of name1, change it to name2, and store it in a string. But Android Studio does not accept a "dynamic" string as a class value.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), string_name.class);
```

You can do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
// Set the component using a String
i.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), string_name);
```

NOTE: Make sure that all of your activities are declared in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you! This finally worked! Can you please explain why this did but the previous ones didn't?

Comment: @master_of_privates `string_name` is an instance of the class `String`, so `string_name.class` returns the `String` class, which is not an `Activity`. You need to get the `Class` object associated with a particular `Activity`. You can also do this using `Class.forName(string_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

***Updated:***
You can use  [Class.forName(String string_name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to get class from a `String`. But in `String` you have to give complete package name of that `class`.

```
    String string_name = "com.your_package.TestActivity";
    try {
        Class<?> classByName = Class.forName(string_name);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, classByName.class);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("YourParentClassName", "System can't find class with given name: " + string_name);
    }
```

Comment: The Class.forName(string_name) is still underlined red and says "Unhandled exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: You can solve this issue putting your code into try-catch:  

         String string_name = "com.your_package.TestActivity";

            try {

                Class<?> classByName = Class.forName(string_name);

                Intent i = new Intent(this, classByName.class);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                Log.e("YourParentClassName", "System can't find class with given name: " + string_name);

            }

Comment: Use Try catch @master_of_privates

Comment: no go. It won't let me initiate the program even with a try/catch. It just refuses to accept a string value as a class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this  snippet should help you:

```
String string_name = "com.package.ActivityToStart";
Intent i = null;
try {
    i = new Intent(this, (Class<?>) Class.forName(string_name).newInstance());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e("YourParentClassName", "System can't find class with given name: " + string_name, e);
}
if (i != null) {
    // do your work
}
```

Comment: This actually managed to get it started, but the intent is not doing it's job. P.S. what do you mean by do your work in the last if clause?

Comment: You should make operations with this intent (such as starting activity) only if intent (in this case "i") is not null. So, here you should put your next code. Have you checked that _i_ is correct intent using debugger or logging? What do you mean  saying "intent is not doing it's job"?

Comment: I mean I tried this code, and the program finally manages to start, but all it does is run the exception code. startActivity(i); still does not go to the next activity

Comment: Have you declared your activities in Manifest? Have you tried to debug this part of code?

Comment: Yep. It was declared.

Answer (score 0):

For a string to class name conversion you need to properly give your package name else it will always throw exception

```
String s = "yourclassname";
try {
  context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Class.forName("your.package.name." + s)));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  Toast.makeText(context, s + " does not exist yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName() used for creating object of class Class. Below is the syntax :

```
Class c = Class.forName(String className)
```

The above statement creates the Class object for the class passed as a String argument(className). Note that the parameter className must be fully qualified name of the desired class for which Class object is to be created. The methods in any class in java which returns the same class object are also known as factory methods. The class name for which Class object is to be created is determined at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to find the solution, I made this pretty cool coding, practically I have given the same name to the activity and the buttons!
I can make unlimited activities and buttons only adding the "click" method to the onclick of the buttons. As long as button and activity have the same name.

```
 public void click (View v){
        Button btn = (Button) v;

        String class_name= "com.example.ex2."+String.valueOf(((Button) v).getText()).toLowerCase();
 
        Log.d("class_name", class_name);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName( getApplicationContext(), class_name);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```